# How to know if a user session is currently open in python daemon

Tags: python, account

I have created a python daemon started on boot-up with launchd.
So this daemon is running before any user has logged in.
But I would like to have a different behavior depending on a user session is open and active or not.
Example:
- no user logged in: behavior 1
- user logged in but not active (while switching to another user): behavior 1
- user logged in and active session: behavior 2

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think [psutils](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/) can do the job:

Exemple:

```
import psutil
psutil.users()
```

Output:

```
[suser(name='giampaolo', terminal='pts/2', host='localhost', started=1340737536.0),
suser(name='giampaolo', terminal='pts/3', host='localhost', started=1340737792.0)]
```

Comment: I have tried it. I gives all the logged in users, not only the current one